# Laravel 5 how relation two fields, date and time in a query with where

Tags: date, laravel-5, time, where-clause, relation

I have two fields in a table: date and time, and I want to show all items with this conditions:

```
 $now = date('Y-m-d');
 $time = date('H:i:s');

 $news = News::where('date', '<=', $now)->where('time', '<=', $time)->where('active', '1')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->orderBy('time', 'desc')->get();
```

And I want to condition the time to the date. I mean that if the date is less than today then the time does not have to affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it as follow:

```
        $news = New::where('date', '<', $now)->where('active', '1')->orWhere('date', '=', $now)->where('time', '<=', $time)->where('active', '1')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->orderBy('time', 'desc')->get();
```

Maybe there's a cleaner way.